# .NET decompiler for Mac or Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, macos, decompiling

I need to decompile a small application written in .NET and convert it to C++. I don't have Windows installed and I know there're a number of .NET decompilers **for Windows**. Since I have only Mac and Linux and don't want to install Windows only to be able to run a decompiler, I wonder, is there any **easy** way to decompile a .NET application in Mac or Linux? I searched for it and didn't find anything.

Comment: Maybe could you run them in Wine?

Comment: This answer was helpful for me https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20619

Answer (score 19):

Since most of the parts of .NET is open-sourced, [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) also works with Linux and Mac.

From project GitHub page:

> Decompiler Frontends
>
> Aside from the WPF UI ILSpy (downloadable via Releases, see also
> plugins), the following other frontends are available:
>
> - Visual Studio 2017/2019 extension marketplace
> - Visual Studio Code Extension repository | marketplace
> - ICSharpCode.Decompiler NuGet for your own projects
> - Linux/Mac/Windows ILSpy UI based on Avalonia - check out    https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvaloniaILSpy
> - Linux/Mac/Windows command line client - check out    ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Console in this repository
> - Linux/Mac/Windows PowerShell cmdlets in this repository

Since [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) works with Linux and Mac, that front end should work in those operating systems too. Command line client should also work.

In addition, JetBrains has a new IDE for .NET, [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). It works in Linux and Mac. Rider has a built-in decompiler. Unfortunately, this built-in compiler, dotpeek, was only available for Windows. But according to comments, dotpeek works in Mac as of 2023 Summer.

Another choice is to use [mono decompiler](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Feb-04.html), a tool from monoproject. Try to use it. Note that this is an add-in in [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/).

Comment: doesn't mono have to be installed?

Comment: crash again and again.

Comment: JetBrains Rider's built in decompiler works for Mac now. (I tested it on M2 Macbook Air)

Answer (score 14):

There's a variant/fork of ILSpy using Avalonia which is available as a packaged MacOS app.

Download from https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvaloniaILSpy/releases

There are instructions for whitelisting the package (which is unsigned) on the page, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If there is an error on launch, run this command
`chmod +x "/Applications/ILSpy.app/Contents/MacOS/ILSpy"`

Answer (score 1):

There is another free option out there - [CodemerxDecompile](https://decompiler.codemerx.com). It is the spiritual successor of JustDecompile - built on an improved version of the same engine with support for the latest frameworks and features. It also works on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

*Disclosure: I'm part of the team behind CodemerxDecompile.*

Comment: watch out that you don't overpromote. see [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

There is monodis in command line disassembler for IL in Mono.
It is possible to use it on Linux and macOS even if you already work with .NET 5 or 6.
However you have to install Mono.

Answer (score -4):

You can decompile an EXE using built-in facilities within Visual Studio for Mac [if you are on OSX].

---

Here's a [step by step walkthrough post](https://blog.motasimfoad.com/post/dotnet/decode_exe/) I wrote!